# What software can I use for remote math tutoring?

Tags: online-instruction, software, interactive-teaching

I am preparing to do some remote tutoring and I am looking for software to help me out.

Requirements:

- Drawing area shared by the tutor and the student, both can draw on the page
- Multiple drawing colors
- Ability to insert images by copy pasting (necessary for pulling in problems from a textbook)
- Ability to export page to PDF

Nice to have:

- Cross platform
- No cost to the student / guest
- Integrated video chat
- Join video chat from separate device

My last requirement is weird. I don't have a proper device with a webcam, so I was hoping to use my phone just for the video chat, until I can get a new laptop.

I have done some research and [Ziteboard](https://ziteboard.com/) is the closest I have found. It seems to support my hard requirements and it works in the browser so it's cross platform. It *looks* like it is free for guests, anyone can make an account for free and the board should get the pro features. It does have integrated video chat, but I can't tell if I could join from a separate device.

[Limnu](https://limnu.com/) appears to also be an option. It's a bit cheaper with no video chat and it's less clear about whether it is free for guests.

I will probably go with Ziteboard if I can't find anything better, but I would like to fully explore the options.

Comment: I have used Microsoft OneNote along with Teams to tutor online and it works brilliantly. I do pay for an Office subscription myself, but my students don't need to pay and I can add them as guests and they get access to my Teams and OneNote for free.

Comment: Going through `wyzant.com` would satisfy your requirements, but Wyzant will take 25% of what the student pays and you get the other 75%